# Rake task which executes other rake tasks via system fails -- no such file to load 'rake'

Tags: path, load, system, rake

I've written a rake task to run a few other rake tasks via system (so as to bind ActiveRecord to different databases, among other things). It works fine on my OS X box, but fails on our production Linux boxes with a load error. The tasks trivially boil down to:

```
namespace :jobs do

  task :foo => :environment do
    system "rake jobs:bar"
  end

  task :bar => :environment do
    puts "foobar"
  end
```

and the traced output is:

```
-bash-3.2$ rake jobs:foo --trace
(in /the/path)
** Invoke jobs:foo (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Erubis 2.6.6
** Execute jobs:foo
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load': no such file to load -- rake (LoadError)
    from /usr/bin/rake:19
```

I dumped a puts $: into /usr/bin/rake and have discovered something interesting. The primary job has a load path containing both of these paths:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib
```

while the secondary job has a load path containing only:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib
```

which probably explains the load error, but not the reason for it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your install has set up the required environment variables correctly.
http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3 
The same problem occurred for me when using "export RUBYOPT=RUBYGEM" instead of "export RUBYOPT=RUBYGEMS". Ahh the difference a single character can make.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be it. The rake executable itself does the require 'rubygems' bit, and the loadpath confirms that rubygems is doing its job, just a bit differently in the two contexts. I'm pretty sure you're right to suggest that it's the environment though, but I can't for the life of me figure out which ones are the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really trying to invoke a rake task from another rake task. Why not do this? "Rake::Task['jobs:bar'].invoke". You can even do it in a loop, for instance an Array#each that changes ENV vars, etc. I've done this in tasks before.

Though, if your example was contrived and your not really calling one task but just asking why the sub shell has different PATH setting, that I do not know. Perhaps if it's hard, then it's a hint that it should be done another way.

Comment: Because I need to bind ActiveRecord::Base to another database, of course, and you yourself told me not to use establish_connection to do it explicitly, and merely changing the ENV vars doesn't change that, nor would it redo any other ENV var specific initializations.